# pandas groupby multiple columns did not sort values by default

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following `df`,

```
code      pct         year_month
10        6.6156      201905
10        6.0868      201905
10        5.8975      201905
10        11.2195     201905
10        11.1404     201905
```

I like to do the following

```
df2 = df.sort_values('pct', ascending=False)
df2['pct'].cumsum().le(20).mean()
0.2
```

in a `groupby` way,

```
df.groupby(['year_month', 'code'])['pct'].apply(lambda x: x.cumsum().le(20).mean())
```

but the result is different,

```
year_month  code
201905      BR10    0.6
```

I thought `groupby` should sort `pct` in descending order by default, but it seems not, so I am wondering how to sort `pct` within in each `year_month`, `code` group first then do the `cumsum`;

Comment: It gives me the same. You do know that you're taking the mean over a series of boolean values?

Comment: @yatu I am using pandas 0.22, whats your version?

Comment: Mine's more recent. Make sure you are working with the same data

Comment: @yatu can you show me your code?

Comment: its the same as yours ...

Comment: I get the same as well, but in your case, maybe try: `df.sort_values(['year_month', 'code', 'pct']).groupby(['year_month', 'code'])['pct'].apply(lambda x: x.cumsum().le(20).mean())`

Comment: @Erfan it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is different, for same output need sorting by first 2 columns - `['year_month','code']` or with this sample data omit it (if already sorted):

```
print (df['pct'].cumsum().le(20).mean())
0.6

df2 = df.sort_values(['year_month','code'], ascending=False)
print (df2['pct'].cumsum().le(20).mean())
0.6
```

In groupby are sorting values in `groupby` - here `['year_month', 'code']`, not `pct`:

```
df = df.groupby(['year_month', 'code'])['pct'].apply(lambda x: x.cumsum().le(20).mean())
print (df)
year_month  code
201905      10      0.6
Name: pct, dtype: float64
```

So for same output sorting here both by `pct` column and if necessary for prevent sorting by `'year_month', 'code']` is added `sort=False`:

```
df2 = df.sort_values('pct', ascending=False)
print (df2['pct'].cumsum().le(20).mean())
0.2

df = (df.sort_values(['pct'], ascending=False)
        .groupby(['year_month', 'code'], sort=False)['pct']
        .apply(lambda x: x.cumsum().le(20).mean()))
print (df)
year_month  code
201905      10      0.2
Name: pct, dtype: float64
```